# How do you make the separation between elements consistent?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to style my elements so that it looks something like this. (The square elements should all be same size)

[image]

But what ends up happening is this: [image]

This is my css code for the container and elements:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 400px;
}

.element {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Just remove justify-content:space between and you can add margin around the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add `align-content: flex-start` to the `.container` style.

> This aligns a flex container's lines within when there is extra space in the cross-axis, similar to how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the main-axis.

[More info about `align-content`.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-8)

Comment: I tried that and now there are no margins between first and second row

Comment: Then you need to add something like `margin-bottom: 10px` to the `.element` style.